# android OutOfMemoryError on WVGA800 and not any small screen format

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

When I try and decode a bitmap on an emulator running less than WVGA800 it works fine (phones included) but on larger screens it throws a OutOfMemoryError

Why would that be? would phones with larger screens have more memory?

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(int assetKey) { return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), assetKey); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Phones with larger displays don't always have more memory than phones will smaller displas. Decoded bitmaps take a lot of of memory, 4 bytes of memory per pixel.

In general it is a good idea to downsample the bitmap if they are too large.  You can do this easily:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = n; // <-- this only decode every nth pixel

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext, rId, ops);
```

Comment: when you say "decode" do you mean it only "grabs" every other pixel? I'm working with spritesheets, not wallpaper sized images -so pixels count

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good practice to break the data in to samples, to avoid memory exception. you can see the following link for that. you have to use sampleSize more than 1. I have resolved my issues by following this post.

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue)